# Incorrect offset of the vertices from a rectangle using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the picture you can see two rectangles with circle marking at the vertices. In the left one I have tried to offset everything by the same distance, but it doesn't work properly. I can't see why because in the right-hand example the circle marking are perfectly on top of each vertex. Why is this? I would be grateful for any help.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,calc}




\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{cyclenode/.style={dashed,very thick,fill=white,circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt}}


% with offset

\draw[draw,purple, dashed,very thick]  (0,0)++(-.2,-.2) rectangle (3,4)++(-.2,-.2);

\path (0,0)++(-.2,-.2) node[cyclenode] {+};
\path (0,4)++(-.2,-.2) node[cyclenode] {-};
\path (3,4)++(-.2,-.2) node[cyclenode] {+};
\path (3,0)++(-.2,-.2) node[cyclenode] {-};


% without offset

\draw[draw,purple, dashed,very thick]  (4,0) rectangle (7,4)++(-.2,-.2);

\path (4,0) node[cyclenode] {+};
\path (4,4)node[cyclenode] {-};
\path (7,4)node[cyclenode] {+};
\path (7,0) node[cyclenode] {-};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `++` syntax isn't really for adding coordinates, but for moving the pen/active point relative to the previous coordinate.

So when you do

```
\draw (0,0) ++(-.2,-.2) rectangle (3,4) ++(-.2,-.2);
```

what happens is

1. place the pen at `(0,0)`
2. move the pen to the point that is `(-.2,-.2)` relative to `(0,0)`
3. draw a rectangle from that point to the point `(3,4)`
4. move the pen to the point that is `(-.2,-.2)` relative to `(3,4)`

However, because the coordinates are parsed as mathematical expressions, you can do e.g.

```
\draw[draw,purple, dashed,very thick]  (-.2,-.2) rectangle (3-0.2, 4-0.2);
```

If you want to do calculations on the "entire" coordinates instead of per component, you can use

```
\draw[draw,purple, dashed,very thick]  ($(0,0) + (-.2,-.2)$) rectangle ($(3,4) + (-0.2,-0.2)$);
```

This dollar sign syntax is defined by the `calc` library, which you already have in your preamble.

Comment: Thanks for the help and insight in the workings of Tikz!